# Como fazer uma div ficar fixa com CSS translate

Tags: jquery, html, css

Tenho um menu mobile que "empurra" o conteúdo para a direita quando é aberto. O problema é que o visitante pode "arrastar" o conteúdo devido ao "translate". Gostaria de fazer o conteúdo ficar fixo. Sem que o usuário arraste, ativando e desativando o menu através do botão somente como já está configurado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
@media (max-width: 979px) {
  body.open-menu-left .page-content {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-260px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-260px, 0, 0);
  }
```

Comment: Tem algum modo de você replicar o código ou disponibilizar via fiddle ou o site (se tiver), para podermos testar e tal? Isso sempre ajuda ...

Comment: por favor disponibilize o código para que possamos ajudar.

Comment: @Bruno Tentei fazer upload usando o Fiddle mas o código fica completamente estranho.

Comment: Este site já está online ? Se sim, passe a url na pergunta.

Comment: @Mastermindsgrp, tente usar uma classe no body para menu ativo/inativo e com isso definir o comportamento de outros elementos dentro da mesma

Comment: @Bruno hospedei ele pra que você possa dar uma olhada. Mastermindsgrp360.com

Comment: Tem usuário e senha para login ....